# Using branch code in package.json from git

Tags: node.js, github, npm, package.json

we are working on node.js application and I consume my colleges package which is published to npm, now he create new Git branch (let's call it second)  there is a way to somehow c**onsume it in the package.json without publish it to npm** ? ( I just want to test the new branch )

**update**
I try something like

`"git://github.mycompany.corp/vv/app.js.git#newbranch"`

and its not working any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so one way is to take the clone of the whole project and 
Try these steps

1) Fetch all the branches

```
git fetch origin
```

2) checkout to your second branch

```
git checkout <second branch name> like
git checkout second
```

3) now test the second branch

Other way could be to use **git subModules** to include the package as the submodule in your project
Please refer this link:

```
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
```

git submodule add git://github.mycompany.corp/vv/app.js.git#newbranch

and then referrence package.json from there and test this.

Comment: THanks but I want to put it in the package.json and install it via npm install...

Comment: Yes please see the update, submodule may work for you as these all are alternates and the 1 answer which is described about referencing git branch in package.json please see this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: Thanks I also tried what you said and its not working, did I do something wrong here ? git://github.mycompany.corp/vv/app.js.git#a05d4b989dc234e26ee14fabb7f2597fc34a5301    , this is what I put in the package.json

Comment: the uuid is the commit sha   .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a particular github branch in package json by adding dependency in below specified format:

```
git://github.com/<user>/<project>.git#<branch>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as is, but removing `.git` worked: `git://github.com/<user>/<project>#<branch>`